# Is there a way we can specify the make files that works with most of the development platforms?

Tags: windows, linux, file, makefile

Is there a way we can specify the make files that works with most of the development platforms? I.e. Linux/Mac/Windows etc

Or something close to that?

Comment: I think you need to be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GNU build system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_build_system) (automake, autoconf, libtool, ...) are exactly made for that : creating a fully portable build system for your software.

Answer (score 2):

Try [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) (cross platform make). It generates Makefiles on Linux and on Windows it generates files for use with nmake.